# Negate Single Quote In Character Class

Tags: regex, bash, sed, regex-negation, single-quotes

I have the following code where I am trying to replace `assign` with `always @(*)` using SED.

Essentially I am trying to ignore the `'` in character class but SED still seems to match it. I don't want sed to catch the line if the line contains a `'` (My regex is much more complicated than this but I want sed to catch lines which my regex and ignore the lines which match my regex but contain a `'`)

```
echo "assign sample_signal = '0;" | sed '/[^\x27]/ {s/assign/always @(*)/g}'
```

Result: `always @(*) sample_signal = '0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please (GNU sed):

```
$ echo "assign sample_signal = '0;" | sed -n '/[\x27]/!{s/assign/always @(*)/g; p}'

$ echo "assign sample_signal = 0;" | sed -n '/[\x27]/!{s/assign/always @(*)/g; p}'
always @(*) sample_signal = 0;
```

Two mistakes you've made:
1. `/[^\x27]/` means to match any character that is not a `'`, but there're many characters that are not `'`, so the regex will match anyway.
2. You didn't use `-n` which is to suppress the output, so match or not, **s**ubstitude or not, the line will be printed out anyway.

So I changed to `/[\x27]/!{}` which means when `\x27` matched, not execute the block `{}`.
(In `sed`'s word, it **will** be executed **when not matched**.)
And by `-n` switch, and `p` in the block, lines with `'` are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `'\''` anywhere you need a `'`:

```
$ echo "f'oo" | sed 's/'\''o/X/'
fXo

$ echo "f'oo" | sed 's/[^'\'']o/X/'
f'X
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose your sed command in double quotes and simply use `/'/!` to apply your command to lines not containing quotes:

```
echo "assign sample_signal = '0;" | sed "/'/! {s/assign/always @(*)/g;}"
```

If there is just one `s` command to apply, you can also omit the braces:

```
echo "assign sample_signal = '0;" | sed "/'/! s/assign/always @(*)/g"
```

As @EdMorton points out in comments, enclosing the command in double quotes may have unwanted effects. You may need to escape dollar sign(`\$`) to avoid unwanted variable expansion in your pattern) and double escape backslashes: `\\\`.